# GridView Sorting with DataSource set from a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datasource

So I got tired of using the GridView's Bound Fields.  I wanted to customize the grid so that I could: 
A: Keep open text boxes editable without switching a row to edit mode.
B: Enable Row by Row updating.  For example I change a value on the row and on the same row click an Update link to commit my change back to the database.  This was partly to allow users to attempt their saves/commits using Update All, then when errors came back in the GridView, they could fix an error, commit it, and move onto the next.  Without losing any of their work or progress as they went.  I manage Cancel functionality and validation through hidden cells that track the original value.
C:  Support a "Update All" link.  So I can change multiple rows and then click Update All.

General "reduce clicks" stuff and I'll admit, just seeing what I could do...

Then I hit Sorting and Paging... Screeching halt.  The best info I found thus far is from the link below.

[HOW TO: Using sorting...](http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx)

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me because I keep getting back a NULL in my GridView's DataSource on PostBack.

Here's what my GridView looks like.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="false" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="RecordID" PageSize="15" width="500px" 
    OnRowCommand="gridview1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <%--RecordID column must remain the first column for accurate functionality.--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RecordID" HeaderText="Record ID" ReadOnly="FALSE" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateAll" runat="server" Text="Update All" OnClick="btnUpdateAll_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering" CommandName="UpdateCUST" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("RecordID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCancel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering" CommandName="CancelCUST" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("RecordID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblField1" runat="server" Text="Business Area"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxField1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCenteringNoBorder"  Text='<%# Bind("Field1") %>' onchange="javascript: RowTextChanged( this )" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="txtbxValidationField1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field1") %>' CssClass="GridViewHiddenCell"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblField2" runat="server" Text="Field2"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxField2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCenteringNoBorder"  Text='<%# Bind("Field2") %>' onchange="javascript: RowTextChanged( this )" > </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="txtbxValidationField2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field2") %>' CssClass="GridViewHiddenCell"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblValidation" runat="server" Text="Validation"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblValidationOut" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering"> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewColHdrCentered" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDelete" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCentering" CommandName="DeleteCUST" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("RecordID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My binding is a simple process of

```
gridview1.DataSource = MyDataSet;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

But since I'm not using an `<asp:SQLDataSource>` or the like, I can't seem to get Sorting working.  I checked the GridView.Rows and wonderfully enough the GridViewRowCollection doesn't seem to have sorting capabilities.

EDIT:  I forgot to mention what I'm working in.
Visual Studio 2013
ASP.Net
.Net 4.0

And before anyone suggests it, sorting by re-querying the data would defeat the behavior I'm looking for.  Specifically Requirement B, being able to do spot updates on the grid.

Comment: Note the article you have linked to is now 8 years old. Ancient in terms on the internet. ASP.net has moved a long way since then. Here's something more up to date: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020310-1.aspx

Comment: On your grid view also add `AllowSorting="true"`

Comment: Allow Sorting by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: The article you linked specifically invalidates the behaviors I'm trying to build in.  Here is some text from the link you provided Jon.  "If you are programmatically binding data to the GridView in lieu of using a data source control then you'll need to create an event handler for the GridView's Sorting event that retrieves the data sorted in the order requested by the end use.".

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid querying the data again.

Comment: A possible option  is to sort the table client side. Look at jQuery and the table sorter plug in (http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Though proceed with cuation and test toughrouly as I seem to recall I had issues with some .net behaviours and client side sorted talbes in the past. If you head towards paging you're going to have even more issues.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".